# How to display user's inputted text from textarea on the same page?

Tags: javascript, html

So here's the idea:
Someone inputs a text on my textarea:
[image]

Then upon clicking on the COUNT button, I want the inputted text to display here:
[image]

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Word Counter</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="input-text-page">
      <h1>Word Counter</h1>
      <form action="">
        <textarea id="inputted-user-text" type="text" rows="22" cols="60"></textarea>
        <br />
      </form>
      <button onclick="countPage()">COUNT</button>
    </div>
    <div id="count-page" style="display: none;">
      <h1>Your Text:</h1>
      <p id=display-user-text></p>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
const countPage = () => {
  const inputTextPage = document.getElementById("input-text-page");
  const countPage = document.getElementById("count-page");

  inputTextPage.style.display = "none";
  countPage.style.display = "block";
};
```

I really don't know how to do this, and I tried googling for the answer. So any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're only hidding the elements, you can still access to it's value.
So before you do `countPage.style.display = "block";`
should be this:

```
const inputUserText = document.getElementById("inputted-user-text");  // Get input text
document.getElementById("display-user-text").innerText = inputUserText.value  // Set text in the other page
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you hiding the elements? Also do you want the word count or the actual text? You change it from title to description to code

Also changed a few html elements and names.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Word Counter</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="input-text-page">
            <h1>Word Counter</h1>
            <textarea id="input-text" type="text" rows="22" cols="60"></textarea><br>
            <button onclick="showResult()">COUNT</button>
        </div>
        <div id="count-page">
            <h1>Your Text: <span id="display-text"></span></h1>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

</html>
```

```js
const showResult = () => {
    //might wanna put these variables somewhere else
    const byId = id => document.getElementById(id);
    const textArea = byId("input-text");
    const output = byId("display-text");

    //if you want the text content and not the count just use textArea.value
    output.textContent = textArea.value.split(" ").length;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to take the text entered in the `#inputted-user-text` and  you have to put it in the `#display-user-text`.

```js
const countPage = () => {
  const inputTextPage = document.getElementById("input-text-page");
  const countPage = document.getElementById("count-page");

  inputTextPage.style.display = "none";
  countPage.style.display = "block";

  let textOut = document.getElementById("display-user-text")
  let textIn = document.getElementById("inputted-user-text").value;
  textOut.innerText = textIn;

};
```

```html
<div id="input-text-page">
  <h1>Word Counter</h1>
  <form action="">
    <textarea id="inputted-user-text" type="text" rows="22" cols="60"></textarea>
    <br />
  </form>
  <button onclick="countPage()">COUNT</button>
</div>
<div id="count-page" style="display: none;">
  <h1>Your Text:</h1>
  <p id=display-user-text></p>
</div>
```